# Call my custom 403 page from htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-403

Is there a way to call my custom 403 page from my htaccess file as I do with my custom 404 page? The way I do with my 404 page is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /404.php [L]
```

So, I want to do the same with my 403 page, not using "ErrorDocument 403 /403.php".

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way using Rewrite Rule, because 403 is the Forbidden status code. And you can´t rewrite this like your 404.

You have to use "ErrorDocument 403 /403.php".